# can not select and edit object

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, uv, modifiers

I am new in blender would you please help me . i attached two file please check.[image]

Comment: Try pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then *Select* again

Comment: what are you trying to select? and what is selected?